# Interface design with in-place operations

Tags: python

My goal is to design the API of a Python library (or actually a C++ library with Python bindings) which:

- Supports *optional* in-place operation.
- Clearly *distinguishes* normal operation from in-place operation.

Essentially this question is about style and conventions.
For *demonstration purposes*, imagine we were (re)designing the API of `numpy` [1]:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5.0)

# a) Returns exp of a (deep) copy
b = np.exp(a)
# b) Also a copy, even though it could theoretically be avoided?
a = np.exp(a)
# c) One option for implementing in-place exp of ndarray
a.exp()
```

Requirements on the API, in order of importance:

1. Not error-prone.
2. Intuitive for a Python user.
3. Familiar from well known packages like numpy, pandas, ... [2].

**Question: What are my options, and what are their pros and cons?**

Options I have considered:

1. Use free functions for normal operation, and methods for in-place operation.

   - If methods return a reference to the object, is this error prone?
   - Methods returning `None` would prevent chaining.
2. Use free functions everywhere, with a special flag to indicate that the input should be replaced: `b = np.exp(a, steal=True)`.
3. Use `numpy`-style `out` argument: `np.exp(a, out=a)`
4. Use free functions with distinct names: `np.exp_in_place(a)`.

<sub>[1] Again, note that I do not actually intend to propose such a change in numpy, this is only to have an example most people should be familiar with.</sub>

<sub>[2] Note that requirement (3.) is deliberately lower priority than (2.) since I assume that some API features for such libraries may simply be historic and potentially different choices would be made if a fresh start was possible.</sub>

Comment: Can you support values of `out` that aren't the input object? NumPy's use of `out` allows far more flexible memory reuse than just in-place operations, giving option 3 a major advantage if you can support the same.

Comment: If you can't support such flexibility, then using `out` gives a misleading impression of your API's capabilities, as well as requiring users to repeat the same argument twice to use it.

Comment: You are right, `out` could refer to any existing object. I did not mention it above since I felt it was irrelevant to the question.